# Why does my multithreaded job queue crash?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, mutex

I'm trying to run a multi-threaded job queue in c++. As an example I have tested the following program:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <list>
#include <vector>


class Job
{
    public:
        void Run(void)
        {
        }
};


class Queue
{
    private:
        std::recursive_mutex mtxJobs;
        std::list<Job *> mJobs;
    public:
        Job *Take(void)
        {
            std::scoped_lock(mtxJobs);
            if (mJobs.size() > 0)
            {
                Job *pJob(mJobs.front());
                mJobs.pop_front();
                return pJob;
            }
            else
                return NULL;
        }

        void Add(Job *pJob)
        {
            std::scoped_lock(mtxJobs);
            mJobs.push_back(pJob);
        }

        size_t Size(void)
        {
            std::scoped_lock(mtxJobs);
            return mJobs.size();
        }
};


void Work(Queue &q)
{
    Job *pJob;
    while ((pJob = q.Take()) != NULL)
    {
        pJob->Run();

        delete pJob;
    }
}

int main()
{
    size_t i;
    Queue q;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        q.Add(new Job);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads(4);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        threads[i] = std::thread(Work, std::ref(q));

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        threads[i].join();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it like this:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -lpthread test.cpp -o test && ./test
```

it crashes with a SEGFAULT. Does anyone have any idea why?

GDB indicates that the crash always occurs when the list 'mJobs' is accessed. However, the locks should prevent concurrent modification right?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Note+ Instead of `new`ing and `delete`ing `Job`s, consider passing around [a `std::unique_ptr<Job>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). it explicitly states the `Job`'s ownership, and pretty much guarantees it's release if anything goes wrong along the way.

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing your queue without synchronization:

```
std::scoped_lock(mtxJobs);
```

this is local variable with name `mtxJobs` which is created taking no arguments and hides your mutex `mtxJobs` member. When `scoped_lock` is created without arguments it does nothing according to [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock/scoped_lock).

You need to write:

```
std::scoped_lock lock(mtxJobs);
```

now, your mutex is locked in ctor of `scoped_lock` object.

Comment: Yep. That's why it's better to use `lock_guard` instead.

Comment: How could I have missed that! I changed it as you said and now I get no more crashes. Thank you!